# Responsive design - Media Queries - How not to load certain images

Tags: css, performance, image, media-queries, responsive-design

Ok, So I designed a responsive layout that doesn't show images for very small screen sizes, using media queries and `display: none;`.

So far so good. But these images still download on these devices, causing an increase in bandwidth.

What is the proper way to make these images not download on the specified devices?

Any response would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you can't just have a different markup setup, I would have a mobile.site.com or www.site.com/mobile concentration point and do something to remove or replace (with a blank or empty file reference) all of the `IMG` src attributes (... or just remove the element altogether...). Or pass all of your image file requests through a script on your server, and set a `COOKIE` or `SESSION` flag that tells the script if it's mobile or not, and send either the file contents or an empty response. Something like that. I don't know that you can do it with pure CSS, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only accessible solution right now is to wrap the image with `<noscript>` tags, then pull the image out later with javascript.** Cookies don't work on first page load (HTMLPreloadScanner), nor with CDNs. Browser-sniffing is useless if your images aren't always 100% of the viewport.

#### [Slimmage.js implements context-friendly responsive images in 3KB of vanilla JS](http://github.com/imazen/slimmage).

The markup is pretty simple as well:

```
<noscript data-slimmage>
  <img src="http://z.zr.io/ri/1s.jpg?width=150" />
</noscript>
```

Of course, you can make a server-side helper to even abstract this away.

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of:

1. Detect small devices on the server using browser-sniffing, and send them different HTML that doesn’t reference the images.
2. Display the images via CSS instead of HTML (in `style` attributes if you like), using either `background-image` or [`:before`/`:after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#before-and-after) and [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) (not supported by IE 6 or 7), and wrap that CSS code in media queries so that it’s only displayed by devices with larger screens.

Comment: #2 would usually be a good solution, sadly it won't work for me in this case

Comment: @Illes: sure, it’s not always a great idea. I think you‘re stuck with serving different HTML to small-screen clients then — I don’t believe browsers let HTML authors control when image assets get downloaded. Hopefully someone else on Stack Overflow will have some experience of this though.

Comment: 2 is a good option because < IE8 doesn't support media queries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a javascript dependency you could check [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth) and insert image tags for sufficiently large screens.

Images would only be requested if javascript is enabled and the window big enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any issues using additional JavaScript, then you may try [THIS](http://adaptive-images.com/). I've stumbled upon it while searching and learning about media queries.